# Load the creative information with the adgroup not just the creative id

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am trying to figure out if anyone has a better way to load facebook adgroups with the creative information. So far the only way I have been able to find is, load all the adgroups using the api point here: /act_{account_id}/adgroups
 I pass the fields 'creative' to get the id, then I have to load all the creatives and pull the data i want.

I can not seem to find a way to filter the creatives to only return the ones I want. Returns all the creatives that ever existed in the account. Seeing that some accounts have 25k+ creatives this is an issue.

The creative endpoint is: '/act_{account_id}/adcreatives/'
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcreative/v2.3

Ideally, it would be amazing if there was a way to just load the creative information directly from the adgroup listing.

I am just looking for a few fields in the adcreative url_tags and object_story_spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nested request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#fieldexpansion) for that. In your case the URL would look like this

`/v2.3/<adgroup_id>?fields=creative{url_tags,object_story_spec}`

Comment: do you know if this is documented somewhere? I do not recall reading anything about this. But this works!

Comment: It's in the hyperlink in my answer. But to be explicit here it is :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#fieldexpansion